# Error reported - how to read the output

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am making some changes to the layout of one of my UIViews (adding additional uitextfields and adding their contents to an email).

I have just run it and get the following error:

```
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#import "RoadSafetyAppAppDelegate.h"

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([RoadSafetyAppAppDelegate class]));
    }
}
```

How am i meant to use this to identify where my error is occurring, and how would i go about fixing it?

Here is the console output:

```
2014-05-20 09:23:20.813 Road Safety App V2[1910:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<Hazard_IdentificationViewController 0x16e6a240> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key HazardLocationNoPhoto.'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x2e881fd3 0x390faccf 0x2e881ce9 0x2f1c5f23 0x2f1d7b55 0x2e7f213b 0x3140cec3 0x3136562b 0x311c1bed 0x310a230d 0x310a2289 0x3114b937 0x311884b3 0x31186deb 0x31185e55 0x31368cab 0x310d3057 0x310d2ff7 0x310d2fd1 0x310be737 0x310d2a4f 0x310d2721 0x310cd6eb 0x310a28ed 0x310a0f97 0x2e84d25b 0x2e84c72b 0x2e84af1f 0x2e7b5f0f 0x2e7b5cf3 0x3370e663 0x3110116d 0x3ad55 0x39607ab7)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

I have removed all visible references to "HazardLocationNoPhoto" and replaced it with "HazardStreet" - where else would it be hiding?

Comment: That isn't the output. That's just a place in your code. The output is in the console.

Comment: There is no error message provided. If it an exception do this and post the results: Add an exception breakpoint. Go to the "Breakpoint Navigator", click on the "+" at the bottom left, select "Add Exception Breakpoint." Run the app to get the breakpoint. When you hit the exception breakpoint click debug continue a couple of times and you will get a backtrace and more error info. Post thatand an exact copy of Xcode/Debugger messages.

Comment: @Zaph here is the console output: `2014-05-20 09:18:08.903 Road Safety App V2[1901:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<Hazard_IdentificationViewController 0x1668ffe0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key HazardLocationNoPhoto.'
"bunch of numbers"
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException`

Comment: Edit your question and add it there, then it will be formatted. Did you add the breakpoint and continue after as in my previous comment?

Comment: @Zaph i have edited the question as requested.

Comment: Do you have a method by that name in the class Hazard_IdentificationViewController? BTW, method names and variable should by convention begin with a lower-case letter.

Comment: no i don't have any method declared - it used to be a variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 2014-05-20 09:23:20.813 Road Safety App V2[1910:60b] *** Terminating
>   app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason:
>   '[
>   setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value
>   coding-compliant for the key HazardLocationNoPhoto.'
>
> I have removed all visible references to "HazardLocationNoPhoto" and
>   replaced it with "HazardStreet" - where else would it be hiding?

It appears that the problem is that a name was changed and not all instances of the name were changed.

Best guess is that you still have `HazardLocationNoPhoto` in Interface Builder.

As a last ditch effort you might open the `.xib` or `.storyboard` file in a text editor and search for `HazardLocationNoPhoto`--just to see if it is there. If found fix it in IB.

Comment: Thank you - Still had that particular text box hidden right under a new one - Fantastic responses and advice given!!!

Comment: For future reference, this exception almost ALWAYS means you've got an IB element hooked to something in a file that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

You need to go to the breakpoint view in the left panel and add a new Exception breakpoint. 
Once you have that, you will be pointed to the right exception line.
The details of the exception are also available in the logs

[image]

Comment: i have done this, and the console is telling me that `[<Hazard_IdentificationViewController 0x16e6a240> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key HazardLocationNoPhoto.'` However, i have removed all references to this textfield in both the .h & .m file.

Comment: if you can paste complete stack trace, you will find the details of the exception

Comment: Have you tried searching for "HazardLocationNoPhoto" throughout the project?